# How can I make the Raspberry Pico not automount as USB storage while using Circuit Python

Tags: python-3, pi-pico, micropython

I am using Circuit Python on a Raspberry Pi Pico to give me hardware buttons for keyboard shortcuts. I am using Circuit Python as opposed to MicroPython because it has the USB_HID library.

I don't want the Pico to automatically mount as USB storage when being plugged in. I just want it to act as a HID device. I am aware that I can write a boot.py script in addition to a code.py but I can't find anywhere online what to put in this which would prevent it from mounting as a USB device. I also still want it to mount as USB sometimes (when a button is pressed/GPIO pin is connected) so there is a still a way for me to change the code on the device.

Is this possible? And, if so, what should the boot.py look like to only mount when a certain GPIO pin is connected?

Comment: Seems this very thing has [been](https://github.com/adafruit/circuitpython/issues/1015) [discussed](https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=136248#p683158) [before](https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=60&t=137940#p682494) in the circuitpython community and git issues